# Pronunciation of "дождь"

Tags: произношение

My dictionary (*Большой универсальный словарь русского языка*) indicates that дождь can be pronounced in two ways /doʂtʲ/ as it is written or /doɕ:/ as if it were written дощ.

Does that hold true for oblique cases as well? In other words can дождя be pronounced /dɐ'ɕ:æ/ as if it were written дощя or perhaps with voicing /dɐ'ʑ:æ/?

Comment: @Elena В Петербурге сегодня дожжи.

Comment: If this question is about omitting д, then yes some people omit it, and @Abakan gives a good example. Listen to this [song](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_5Ur6IjrtP8) at 1:53 to hear plural of дождь as [дожжи]. (Excuse my using letters instead of proper transcription symbols). So, if a person prefers to pronounce дожжь instead of дождь, this person will do it in all grammatical cases and in plural too. Nom: дожжь дожжи, Gen: дожжя дожжей, Dat: дожжю, дожжям, Acc: дожжь, дожжи, Inst: дожжём дожжями, Prep: о дожже, о дожжях.

Comment: @Abakan It's **never** "дощщ" or "дожжи" (old Moscow pronunciation style) in _St. Petersburg_; "дошть" and "дожди" is correct there.

Comment: @Alex_ander it depends on a speaker (or a singer in this case) not on place.

Comment: @Abakan As I can remember from my childhood, _everybody_ found it funny to hear _дожжи_ from Moscow TV announcers. There are some variations now due to migration, but this aspect of pronunciation mainly depends on the speaker's _place of birth_ and doesn't change later. For example, Bulat Okudzhava who lived in Moscow did't say _дожжи_ since his parents came from Tbilisi.

Comment: On the contrary, there is V. Bortko, a Moscow-born film director specializing in criminal drama movies. Typically, the action takes place in St.Petersburg, where Bortko lives now. It was a bit strange to hear dialogues in his works with phrases like "Мы в Питере к _дожжям_ привычные" or the word "архаровцы" in its original sense (cruel police officers named so after a former Moscow governor).

Comment: I have heard multiple times this word to be pronounced as "дощ" throughout my life, so it is a valid, but quite rare pronunciation.

Comment: Now when we have a detailed [video](https://youtu.be/yY7zXn2FU3g) about Old Moscow pronunciation style (see around minute 11), we have to agree with @Alex_ander: the pronunciation depends on geographical place where the person come from. See the map in the video at 16:24. :-)

Answer (score 3):

Shortly speaking - no, even if someone pronounces /doɕ:/ и "по дождём" most likely "ж" will be clearly articulated - there are some variations though where /d/ could be omitted or "ж" will be geminated and/or palatalized.

However, as it was mentioned in [this post](https://russian.stackexchange.com/questions/420/pronunciation-norm), the pronunciation norm in Russian is not set in stone and in some cases there can be surprising variations. If I would hear something like /dɐ'ɕ:æ/ I would most likely recognize it though might find it odd.

Answer (score 3):

Two-consonant [ʐdʲ] ([ʂtʲ] unvoiced in Nominative): [Зимовье зверей - Ход дождём](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PLlKnoMOBn4) - multiple occurences in nearly all grammar cases. As the singer is from Sankt-Peterburg (then Leningrad), it could be accepted as excellent example of this norm.

Similarly: [Игорь Корнелюк - Дожди](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zGJYd2FIo2k&t=46) - rhymed "подожди" and "дожди"; may be also treated as SPb variant. (But it could have also rhymed with [ʑː] in both, with the same success.)

A likely Moscow variant with [ʑː] is noted in comments to the question.

Recorded dialects include variants as [ʐdʲʑ], [ʑdʲʑ], [ʑː], [ʐː] as well (with respective devoicing).

Anyway, the main thing here is that this consonant sequence is normally voiced (and can be voiceless only at word end position).

Fully voiceless implementation is, to compare with, in Ukrainian (and respectively spelled: дощ - доща - дощу - ...); common norm requires [ʂtʂ] here ([ɕtʲɕ] in дощі).

Comment: Good illustration of pronunciation in St. Petersburg - with Kornelyuk's song.

Comment: @Alex_ander But why IYO it's better than K. Arbenin's one? Nearly just curious.

Comment: I was only familiar with Kornelyuk's song, so I liked your observation on rhymes in it.